# ElementTree Remove Element

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, scripting, elementtree

Python noob here. Wondering what's the cleanest and best way to **remove** all the "`profile`" tags with `updated` attribute value of `true`.

I have tried the following code but it's throwing: **SyntaxError("cannot use absolute path on element")**

```
 root.remove(root.findall("//Profile[@updated='true']"))
```

XML:

```
<parent>
  <child type="First">
    <profile updated="true">
       <other> </other>
    </profile>
  </child>
  <child type="Second">
    <profile updated="true">
       <other> </other>
    </profile>
  </child>
  <child type="Third">
     <profile>
       <other> </other>
    </profile>
  </child>
</parent>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are using `xml.etree.ElementTree`, you should use [`remove()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.remove) method to remove a node, but this requires you to have the parent node reference. Hence, the solution:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

data = """
<parent>
  <child type="First">
    <profile updated="true">
       <other> </other>
    </profile>
  </child>
  <child type="Second">
    <profile updated="true">
       <other> </other>
    </profile>
  </child>
  <child type="Third">
     <profile>
       <other> </other>
    </profile>
  </child>
</parent>"""

root = ET.fromstring(data)
for child in root.findall("child"):
    for profile in child.findall(".//profile[@updated='true']"):
        child.remove(profile)

print(ET.tostring(root))
```

Prints:

```
<parent>
  <child type="First">
    </child>
  <child type="Second">
    </child>
  <child type="Third">
     <profile>
       <other> </other>
    </profile>
  </child>
</parent>
```

---

Note that with `lxml.etree` this would be a bit simpler:

```
root = ET.fromstring(data)
for profile in root.xpath(".//child/profile[@updated='true']"):
    profile.getparent().remove(profile)
```

where `ET` is:

```
import lxml.etree as ET
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I formatted my actual XML implementation and your code didnt remove the Profile tag on it. (Not your fault). I'll accept your answer and repost a new question.

Comment: @user1195192 don't worry - just update the XML and I'll update the code appropriately.

Comment: thanks. I figured it out. Needed another for loop. lxml code looks so much cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

I searched for a way directly addressing the elements to be deleted, using built-in `xml` library. Here is the solution:

```py
import itertools
from xml.etree import ElementTree

def removeall(root: ElementTree.Element, match, namespaces=None):
    parent_by_child=dict(itertools.chain.from_iterable(
        ((child, element) for child in element) for element in root.iter()))

    for element in root.findall(match, namespaces):
        parent_by_child[element].remove(element)
```

Applied on your data:

```py
data = """
<parent>
  <child type="First">
    <profile updated="true">
       <other> </other>
    </profile>
  </child>
  <child type="Second">
    <profile updated="true">
       <other> </other>
    </profile>
  </child>
  <child type="Third">
     <profile>
       <other> </other>
    </profile>
  </child>
</parent>"""

root = ElementTree.fromstring(data)
removeall(root, ".//child/profile[@updated='true']")
print(ElementTree.tostring(root, encoding='unicode'))
```

Prints:

```xml
<parent>
  <child type="First">
    </child>
  <child type="Second">
    </child>
  <child type="Third">
     <profile>
       <other> </other>
    </profile>
  </child>
</parent>
```

As the question is marked with python2.7: I need to admit that I do not know whether the `itertools.chain.from_iterable` that I used to built up the child-parent-dict was already present in python2.7.